# PHP get value from sql query (use implode/explode?)

Tags: php, sql

I am running the below query. I can use the `ticket_cost` result column, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to pull the other data from the result.

```
$sql = "SELECT ticket_cost, GROUP_CONCAT(game ORDER BY game DESC SEPARATOR '|') FROM games WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', $myIDArray) . ") GROUP BY ticket_cost ORDER BY ticket_cost DESC";
$myresult = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
```

Result looks something like this in phpmyadmin:

```
ticket_cost   |   GROUP_CONCAT(game ORDER BY game DESC SEPARATOR '|')
    10            thisIsATest|thisIsATest2|thisIsATest3
    5             thisIsAnotherTest
```

To display, I'm using:

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach($myresult as $row2)
    {
        echo "This doesn't work:" . $row2['game'];
        echo "<li>" . $row2['ticket_cost'] . "</li>";
    }
echo "</ul>";
```

This displays:
This doesn't work:
10
5

How can I display each of the pipe ("|") separated result items after each respective `ticket_cost`?

Comment: use alias `GROUP_CONCAT(game ORDER BY game DESC SEPARATOR '|') as games` and then use `$row['games']`

Answer (score 1):

Use alias

**Query**

```
$sql = "SELECT ticket_cost, GROUP_CONCAT(game ORDER BY game DESC SEPARATOR '|') AS gameData FROM games WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', $myIDArray) . ") GROUP BY ticket_cost ORDER BY ticket_cost DESC";
$myresult = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
```

**PHP Code**

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach($myresult as $row2)
{
    $gameData = explode("|", $row2['gameData']);
    foreach($gameData as $row3)
    {
        echo "<li>" . $row3 . "</li>";
        echo "<li>" . $row2['ticket_cost'] . "</li>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

**Output**

```
ticket_cost       GameData
-----------       -----------
    10            thisIsATest
    10            thisIsATest2
    10            thisIsATest3
    5             thisIsAnotherTest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also access that data without modifying your query. When you are accessing the result, access the value using [mysqli_result::fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

**PHP Code**

```
echo '<ul>';
while($row2 = $myresult->fetch_array())
{
    // Your game data is the 2nd value in your select, so
    // access it with the 0-based index of [1]
    $gameData = explode('|', $row2[1]);
    foreach ($gameData as $game)
    {
        echo '<li>' . $game . ' $'. $row2['ticket_cost'] . '</li>';
    }
}
```

**Output**

- thisIsATest $10
- thisIsATest2 $10
- thisIsATest3 $10
- thisIsAnotherTest $5